# Why this statement cannot be updated in the database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am facing this issue with my query. I would like you to kindly help me resolve it.

```
   MD = "UPDATE librarysystem.audit set timeout = '" & Today + "" + TimeOfDay & "' AND status='0' WHERE username = '" & AccountId & "'AND status = '1'"
           cmd = New MySqlCommand(MD, con)
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

here's the code:

```
    connect()

    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To LOGOUT?", "Are You?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = DialogResult.No Then
        Me.Show()
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then

        connect()
        Dim time As DateTime
        time = Date.Today
        Dim a As Integer = 0
        MD = "UPDATE librarysystem.audit set timeout = '" & Today + "" + TimeOfDay & "' AND status='0' WHERE username = '" & AccountId & "'AND status = '1'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(MD, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        AccountSettings.Hide()
        BorrowedBooks.Hide()
        LogHistory.Hide()
        Login.Hide()

        ReturnedBooks.Hide()
        SearchBooks.Hide()

    End If
End Sub
```

:

Thank you in advance ^^

Comment: Can you pls add some details about your database, like the ER diagram or data dictionary.

Comment: And also pls add some code snippet. It's really difficult to just Judge the problem with a mere sql syntax

Comment: You didnt share the error involved but there is a very good chance that using SQL PArameters will fix the issue.  You should also not be reusing DB provider objects

Comment: change **AND status='0'** to **, status='0'**

Comment: @shinbona Don't change the original question after you solved your issue.  Also you don't need to add CLOSED in the title or "this is solved" in the body of the question. if you accepting answer that means you found the answer you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the deep hassles of SQL is that you're usually embedding one language in another. That makes it hard to read things in both languages clearly. Here's your SQL extracted from your vb.

```
UPDATE librarysystem.audit
   set timeout = '" & Today + "" + TimeOfDay & "'
   AND status='0'
 WHERE username = '" & AccountId & "'AND status = '1'"
```

Here it is with some sample values substituted

```
UPDATE librarysystem.audit
   set timeout = '2016-11-26 13:14:15'
   AND status='0'
 WHERE username = 'SomeUserName'AND status = '1'
```

You should be able to carry out that statement directly on your dbms and have it function correctly.  But, look it over. What do you see?

I see an `AND` where there should be a `,` in the list of columns to update. `AND` only works in `WHERE` and `ON` clauses, not in lists of columns.

I see a missing space in the SQL in the sequence `'SomeUserName'AND`.

I also see some potential confusion in the way your vb program created the value for `timeout`. It's not immediately clear whether your vb `TimeOfDay` variable will render in 24h format (`13:14:15`) or in am/pm format (`01:14:15 PM`).

Finally, I see an extraordinarily common mistake. The SQL statement is [jammed onto one line](http://www.mostlymaths.net/2014/01/the-mandelbrot-set-in-one-line-of-apl.html), as if it had been written in the 1980s by a psychotic [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) programmer.  This makes your language-in-a-language program almost impossible to read.

Comment: thank you so much, and the missing space is the problem now i know :) thank you so much for the information again. I learned a lot :D